# Training tracker for SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, training

I had seen your video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sKAuM46qW3I
Can you provide me the kink to the STP file you designed for training tracking??
I could not find it with the li

Answer (score 1):

I do not have that information any more. It was primarily for SharePoint 2007. The Fab 40 templates din't port well from 2007 to 2010 to 2013.